# (JS) Very confused about Promises with fetch

Tags: javascript

I have seen many youtube videos/courses/"books" on promises with fetch, but they didn't help. This is just confusing.

I understand this bit:

```
fetch("some url/file")   // get "data" from some API and it returns a promise

.then( res => res.json()) // this is a promise but not the raw data that we need

.then(data => console.log(data) // with this I will actually access the actual data

.catch( err => console.log(err) // this is if errors exists but ONLY if It can't open the actual site, like their server is dead or whatever, I know that with an IF statements I can check if the status is 200 and that can work with errors.
```

I was reading more about it and a site said "The new Promise() constructor should only be used for legacy async tasks, like usage of setTimeout or XMLHttpRequest. A new Promise is created with the new keyword and the promise provides resolve and reject functions to the provided callback:"" ,but then what about resolve and reject? Do I even need them?

Then, I read on stackoverflow that if you are fetching, you don't need to make a "new Promise" because fetch already returns a promise(though in the stackoverflow example the person was writing it like this, in a variable"

```
function get(url) {

console.log('Making fetch() request to: ' + url);

let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

fetch(url).then  // etc etc
")
```

So the main questions are:

1. What about "new Promise"? What is it? Do I need it? When? Talk to me about it.
2. If I need "new Promise", do I put it into a variable (let test = new Promise) or do I return it in a function (function test(){ return new Promise}) //etc etc, what is the difference?
3. If I need "new Promise", when do I resolve and reject? WHAT do I resolve/reject?

If you want to answer these questions with an in depth link, explaining it, feel free.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Minor point: You're missing a `)` at the end of `.then(data => console.log(data)`.

Comment: Simple rule of thumb. If a method has a `.then()` property...it is already a promise

Comment: I'm glad I switched to `async await`, especially for `fetch`. It's just so much more readable! `async loadData(){this.data = (await fetch(url)).json()}` That's it!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comments on that fetch code are mostly correct, except that because the `catch` is at the end of the chain, it doesn't *only* receive failures from the original `fetch`; if there's an error thrown within one of the `then` callbacks preceding it (or a promise returned from one that ultimately rejects), it'll see that error. For instance, with this code if the `fetch` succeeds the `catch` handler receives the error thrown by the `then` callback:

```
fetch(/*...*/)
.then(response => throw new Error("fail"))
.catch(err => {
    // Either gets error from `fetch` or failure from `then` above
});
```

Similarly, in your quoted code, if the promise returned by `response.json()` *rejects* (can't read the body, invalid JSON, etc.), your `catch` handler will see that rejection (error).

> ...what about resolve and reject? Do I even need them?

Not in that code, no.

> 1. What about "new Promise"? What is it? Do I need it? When?

You need it when you don't have a promise already and you need a promise chain. You **don't** need it when you have a promise already (such as the one from `fetch`) and need a promise chain.

> 2. If I need "new Promise", do I put it into a variable (let test = new Promise) or do I return it in a function (function test(){ return new Promise}) //etc etc, what is the difference?

There's nothing special about promises in that regard. If you need to refer to it later within the same scope, use a variable. If not, you can return it directly (if returning it).

> 3. If I need "new Promise", when do I resolve and reject? WHAT do I resolve/reject?

You call `resolve` when whatever non-promise activity you're doing completes. You pass it the value that activity generated (if there is one).

You call `reject` when whatever non-promise activity you're doing *fails*. You pass it the same thing you'd use with `throw`: An error of some kind. (Typically by creating it as an actual error, e.g., `new Error(...)`).

More reading on `new Promise`: [*What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine `fetch` and `response.json()` you do not have to return a `new Promise` because `fetch` is already a promise. You can just return the `fetch().then(...)`

For example

```
const fetchJson = url =>
  fetch(url).then(r=>g.json());
```

You can use `new Promise` when you want to call an API that takes callbacks and turn it into a promise instead.

For example:

```
const classicApiToPromise = arg =>
  new Promise(
    (resolve,reject)=>
      classicApi(
        arg,
        (data,err)=>//classic callback
          (err)
            ? reject(err)
            : resolve(data)
      )
  );
```